# How to send selected option's parameter to controller in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Could you help me how to send selected option's parameter to controller? Here is my view:

```
<select>
   @foreach(var item in Model.City)
   {      
      <option>@Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Name)</option>

   }
</select>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

so, in your view you would have something like:

```
@model MyModel

@using(Html.BeginForm()) {

  <select id="City" name="City">
    @foreach(var c in Model.City)
    {
      <option value="@c.Id">@c.Name</option>
    }
  </select>

  <input type="submit" value="Post data to controller" />

}
```

in your controller, all you have to do is have an action with the same name, but with a different signature:

either:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(string City) { ... }
```

or you can pass the entire Model

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(MyModel model) { 
  string city = model.City;
}
```

---

but with such question, **I would suggest** you to spend some time with the free ASP.NET Course from PluralSight  that you can find in the ASP.NET oficial website:

**Free available courses**:

- for ASP.NET **WebPages**: http://www.asp.net/web-pages
- for ASP.NET **WebForms**: http://www.asp.net/web-forms
- for ASP.NET **MVC**: http://www.asp.net/mvc

*courses are in the right sidebar of each page*

And from **Scott Hanselman**:

- [**Choosing** the Right Programming Model](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/choosing-the-right-programming-model)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing the form html helper. Try this (it assumes that you're going to the Controller/Index action read up on BeginForm helper if you need to specify a different ActionResult):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
    <select>
    @foreach(var item in Model.City)
    {

        <option>@Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Name)</option>    
    }
    </select>

    <br />

    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}
```

Rather than iterating through Model.City, you should look at another Html helper like Html.DropDownList.